# Storing data larger than machine memory into database

Tags: memory-management, couchbase, document-oriented-db, bigdata, nosql

How or what ways I would need to store an amount of data that is larger than machine memory into database (Ex. data is 20 GB, RAM is 16 GB). Considering I am using one machine, and all the data is document oriented (NoSQL)

Comment: What do you want to do with this data?

Answer (score 0):

The most easy solution is to use [wiredtiger](http://wiredtiger.com/). It's an embedded key-value store with ACID guarantees. It's unlike REDIS.